# Using linq to group by and merge property values of duplicates

Tags: c#, linq

Given a list of objects how can I group by and merge using Linq in C#

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<ItermsPerPerson> authors = new List<ItermsPerPerson>()
        {
            new ItermsPerPerson("Joe", "Pens"),
            new ItermsPerPerson("Jim", "Pencils"),
            new ItermsPerPerson("Joe", "Cycle"),
        };

        var list = authors.GroupBy(g => g.Name).ToList();
        Console.WriteLine(list);
        Console.WriteLine(list.Count);
    }

    class ItermsPerPerson 
    {
        public ItermsPerPerson(string name, string itemType)
        {
            Name = name;
            ItemType = itemType;
        }

        public string Name {get; set;}

        public string ItemType {get; set;}
    }
}
```

Give the above example I would like to group by name and merge item type, so the resulting list would contain two items with something similar to:

```
Name    ItemType
====================
"Joe"   "Pens, Cycle"
"Jim"   "Pencils"
```

TIA and Apologies if this has come up before, all searches with similar keywords on here resulted in code which grouped and sum/count another property, which is not what I am after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `GroupBy` and then recreate the `ItermsPerPerson` by a concatenate the `ItemType`

```
var rs = authors.GroupBy(c => c.Name)
       .Select(g => new ItermsPerPerson(g.Key, string.Join(",", g.Select(r => r.ItemType)))
```

Answer (score 1):

So by the example all you want to do with the `ItemTpye` is concatenate the values. For that add a projection (`.Select`) to change each grouping item to match that:

```
var list = authors.GroupBy(g => g.Name)
                  .Select(g => new ItermsPerPerson(g.Key, string.Join(", ", g.Select(i => i.ItemType))));
```

You could also use the overload of `GroupBy` to select what is kept for each item:

```
var list = authors.GroupBy(k => k.Name, v => v.ItemType)
                          .Select(g => new ItermsPerPerson(g.Key, string.Join(", ", g)));
```